# Consistent spacing after section?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, sectioning

Effectively, when I make section titles, I noticed that obviously the space after them is constant, but the letters aren't mono-width, leading to weird discrepancies across them. Is there any way to make the space after a subsubsection to adapt to this so that all the starting lines are aligned?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\alph{subsubsection})}

\begin{document}
\section{Dolor Sit Amet}
\subsubsection{Lorem Ipsum}
\subsubsection{Lorem Ipsum}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to right align the subsection numbers within a small space.

If this causes problems in the TOC etc., try `\hbox to 1em{\hfill...}` or use `\protect`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\makebox[1em][r]{\alph{subsubsection})}}

\begin{document}
\section{Dolor Sit Amet}
\subsubsection{Lorem Ipsum}
\subsubsection{Lorem Ipsum}
\end{document}
```

---

This version modifies `\@seccntformat`.  Rather than do a string compare, I defined different formats for every possible `\@sect` name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\alph{subsubsection}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\section@format}{\thesection\quad}
\newcommand{\subsection@format}{\thesubsection\quad}
\newcommand{\subsubsection@format}{\makebox[1em][r]{\thesubsubsection})\quad}
\newcommand{\paragraph@format}{\theparagraph\quad}
\newcommand{\subparagraph@format}{\thesubparagraph\quad}
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname #1@format\endcsname}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Dolor Sit Amet}
\subsubsection{Lorem Ipsum}
\subsubsection{Lorem Ipsum}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you redefine \thesubsubsection like this you are also affecting references. It is better to change `\@seccntformat`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer how would you go about doing that?

Comment: Note that \@seccntformat is passed section, subsection, etc. as an argument.

Comment: you don't have to define a format for every level. You could do something like `\ifcsname #1@format\endcsname \csname#1@format\endcsname \else \csname the#1\endcsname\quad\fi`, and then define only the new \subsubsection@format.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - or use \@ifundefined etc.  OTOH, I have always preferred jump vectors to test-and-branch.